# Getting Bar in barplot all the same size across multi panel barplots

Tags: r, plot, par

I have a curious question, I am using par() to make a muli-panel barplot, I notice that the bars are different sizes, I was wondering if it is possible to make the bars the same width (size) across each panel? This would create different size panels, but this would be fine. Any comments would be helpful.

I have this generic example:

```
# create data
a<-c(1:100)
b<-c(1:200)
c<-c(1:300)
d<-c(1:400)
e<-c(1:500)

#make dataframes for barplots
test<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
test1<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
test2<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))
test3<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d,e))

#gets means for each column
a1<-colMeans(test)
a2<-colMeans(test1)
a3<-colMeans(test2)
a4<-colMeans(test3)

#lets plot
pdf(file= "/Users/Highf_000/Desktop/prac.pdf");
par(mfrow = c(2, 4),     # 2 rows x 4 columns layout
      oma = c(2, 2, 0, 0), # two rows of text at the outer left and bottom margin
      mar = c(5, 5, 2, 1)+0.1, # space for one row of text at ticks and to separate plots
      mgp = c(2, 1, 0),    # axis label at 2 rows distance, tick labels at 1 row
      xpd = NA) 

barplot(mean(a))
barplot(a1)
barplot(a2)
barplot(a3)
barplot(a4)

dev.off()
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmdz8.png)

[image]

[After Rebecca's suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWNme.png)

[image]

How do we overcome the plot disappearing in a multiple plot layout and how do we fix the title to be centered over the bars not the plot?

Comment: There is already an answer to this question, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525285/how-to-make-barplot-bars-same-size-in-plot-window-in-r-using-barplot-function?rq=1)

Comment: @ Rebecca, can you explain how the xlim and width commands work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying your example

```
a1 <- c(1,2)
a2 <- c(1,2,3)
a3 <- c(1,2,3,4)

barplot(a1) ## produces uneven bars
barplot(a2) ## produces uneven bars
barplot(a3) ## produces uneven bars
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525285/how-to-make-barplot-bars-same-size-in-plot-window-in-r-using-barplot-function?rq=1), you can do at least one of the following:

Option 1

```
df <- data.frame(bar1 = c(1, 2, 0,0), 
                 bar2 = c(1, 2, 3, 0), 
                 bar3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

barplot(as.matrix(df), beside = TRUE)
```

Option 2

```
bar1 <- barplot(a1, xlim = c(0, 1), width = 0.1)
bar2 <- barplot(a2, xlim=c(0,1), width = 0.1)
bar3 <- barplot(a3, xlim=c(0,1), width = 0.1)
```

There's also the ggplot option is you are not keen on barplot.

Comment: @ Rebecca and general more experienced Rgrammers. Using what Rebecca does works, but this leads to other problems. See updated image.

Comment: If the suggestion solved your problem, please accept it as an answer. Regarding the second point, I am unclear how you want the plot to look, perhaps you can explain a bit further? Also, consider opening a new post with your (new) question?